# How to centered TextInput on page in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When TextInput focused and android keyboard opened need to centered TextInput on screen above keyboard. Ho to make it?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason justifyContent is not working for TextInput so just use margins. Here is example:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginRight: 50
  }
});
```

Just make sure to set styles to TextInput:

```
<TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
```

Almost forgot - do not set width, use margins to define size, or it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use flexbox.

On the parent container you'll need something like:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contaner: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center
    }
});
```

Here is a good guide to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: `display` is a CSS property and not valid for react-native. See also: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/298

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just had the same issue, and found a solution, so I thought I'd share for anyone else having this problem.

I have a container with styles:

```
flex:1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center'
```

Within that container I have several `Text` elements, along with a `Slider` and `TextInput`. Everything was centered properly except the `TextInput`.  To solve this, I added the following to the styles for my `TextInput`:

```
alignSelf: 'center'
```

And now the `TextInput` is properly centered on the screen.